# Unable to access 'FileProperties' JSON of document uploaded to Content Hub DAM to retrieve file extension

Tags: content-editor, content-hub, nextjs, javascript, typescript

Running Sitecore.NET 10.3.0 - November 01, 2022
.NET Framework 4.8

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the FileProperties (JSON values) that contains metadata information regarding files uploaded to Sitecore Content Hub DAM.

In [Sitecore OOTB Schema](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/manage--ootb-schema.html), there are two properties which are of interest to me:

- FileProperties
- FileSize

I was able to get FileSize by adding an entry in `/sitecore/system/Modules/DAM/Config/Mapping/General Link Field/filesize` and then serializing it. I was able to access `filesize` in code (TSX) by simply doing:

```
const AccessibleLink = (props: any): JSX.Element => {
    const linkField = (props.field.value as LinkFieldValue);
    const fileSize = linkField?.filesize;
```

but when I try do the same with `fileproperties`

- added in Content Editor `/sitecore/system/Modules/DAM/Config/Mapping/General Link Field/fileproperties`
- dotnet sitecore ser pull
- in TSX code: `console.log(linkField.fileproperties)`

I get an undefined value in devtools console...

Why is this? The [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/31/content-hub/administration--using-metadata-configuration.html) mentions that `FileProperties` will have the following values:

```
        "FileProperties": {
        "bag": "properties",
        "properties": {
          "extension": "extension",
```

but I fail to retrieve this in code even though `filesize` works but not `fileproperties`.

Comment: does it have something to do with **mapping** that entry `/sitecore/system/Modules/DAM/Config/Mapping/General Link Field/fileproperties`  to a javascript component to view the file properties values?